# Where to place my summary row

Tags: gui-design, user-expectation, placement

I am currently working on a **event scheduling page** and I am not sure where to show the **summary of the event scheduled**.

I have shown it on the top right corner but I feel it can be shown in some other place. Which place do you think will be the right fit? I have attached the screenshot fo reference.

[image]

Comment: Is the summary the duration of the event? So the user would make the scheduling inside the form and then they will see the summary?

Comment: yes, it is the duration of the event.

Answer (score 2):

I frankly didn't even notice it until I read the question a second time and noticed you mentioned placing it in the top right corner, so I think that validates your concern. For the sake of simplicity, I would place it between the "Basic Information" title and "Assignment Description" section. I also have a question related to the Summary: your screenshot denotes that it describes the duration of the task, is that true?

Comment: Yes it denotes the duration of the task.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah agree with Stefan, you need to show the summary after the details have been added in. So after "Basic Information". Ideally, they summary details would update as additions are made, if appropriate to keep the user informed.

I would also recommend strengthening the style so it stands out more.

Comment: Yes, I am planning to push it below the basic information section.